# read multiple inputs from same line in java

Tags: java

Here is my code snippet

```
public void m1(int a) // a value passed from main
{
  for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
   {
         // Read "a" inputs from the user one by one
   }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
  int a;
       // read value of a from user
  m1(a)
 }
```

Can U please tell me how to give this input in one line.
Like in the same line we need to provide the value of a and also should take a values from user.

eg:`enter code here`
a=6. 6 values from user
6 22 33 44 55 66

6 and the 6 inputs from the user should be in the same line (given by the user at the same time).

Comment: like your input will be: 6 11 22 33 44 55 66 (all in same line)??

Comment: Yes @Shahid 
all number  should be in the same line itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go this way:

```
public class Number {    
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int arr[];

    public static void read(int a)
    {       
        arr = new int[a];
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.print("Enter numbers here : ");
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        read(a);

        // printing the array
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

But better and cleaner way will be returning the array from `read` method:

```
public class Number {    
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static int[] read(int a)
    {        
        int arr[] = new int[a];
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        return arr;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.print("Enter numbers here : ");
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        int numbers[] = read(a);

        // printing the numbers array
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            System.out.print(numbers[i]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Input:

```
Enter numbers here : 4 1 2 3 4
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Solve that your problem? I haven't understand exactly what you want, but with this you can do anything, or not?

```
public static void m1(String[] a) // a value passed from main
{
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        // Read "a" inputs from the user one by one
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    m1(args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void m1(int a) // a value passed from main
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int arr[] = new int[a];
  for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
   {
         arr[i]=scan.nextInt();
   }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
  int a=(int) 6.6;
       // read value of a from user
  m1(a);
 }
```

Comment: why the input is 6.6 where question mentioned integer? again you should return the array from the method, otherwise the array'd be good for nothing.

Comment: Venki WAR. a can be any value given by the user. I just mentioned 6 as an example, Even a should be given by the user itself.

Answer (score 0):

**Input:**

```
1 -2 "nonumber" 34
```

**Output:**

```
1
-2
34
```

**Code:**

```
String line = scanner.nextLine();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
while (m.find()) {
   System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, a couple of quick pointers:

- Name your methods something more practical than m1()

- Make sure you end your statements with a semi-colon ( e.g m1() )

- You need to define m1() as static, or otherwise instantiate the class which contains m1()

- Learn about Scanners and Arrays; you must import a library to use a Scanner object. ( import java.util.Scanner; )

```
public static void storeIntegers(int a){ 

      //This is how you declare an array.
      int[] someIntArray = new int[a];

      //You must create a Scanner object to take in user input.
      Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

      for(int i = 0; i < a; i++){

             someIntArray[i] = userInput.nextInt();
       }

      // Just to make sure it worked.
      for(int e = 0; e < someIntArray.length; e++){
          System.out.println(someIntArray[e]);
      }


    }// End storeIntegers()

    public static void main(String[] args){

      Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("How many numbers?");
      int a = userInput.nextInt();

      storeIntegers(a);

     }// End main()
```